# Update variable information in the openwrt web interface luci

Tags: lua, openwrt

[image]

From the picture we see the value of `RSSI`, there is a code on `lua` and sh that displays this value, the script sh writes a value to the file, in `lua` we write it to a variable from the file and assign it to the label element

```
os.execute('/bin/rssi')
file = io.open("/tmp/rssi", "r");
d:option(DummyValue, "label", "rssi: "..(file:read("*line")));
file:close();
```

Everything works, but I want to see information in the web interface every N second. I will be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's something that has to be implemented at the frontend (HTML, JS, PHP), not in the Lua backend.  I don't know how the kids do it these days, but from what I know, you'd need to use JavaScript to refresh that part of the HTML document every few seconds, as you want.

The way it works is as such:

1. Request a web page from Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Edge;
2. Web server opens requested file, if file is a script, script runs;
3. Script retrieves data from systems, databases, etc.;

   3.1 Lua script runs, returns value (of RSSI, for you);

   3.2 Script replaces variable by value returned by Lua script;

   3.3 Script returns HTML code where variables have been replaced by values from databases, systems, etc.;
4. Web server sends data over the network;
5. Client web browser displays the data, usually as a HTML document formatted by CSS, with JavaScript interactivity, and automatic activities.

In your case, you'd want this:

6. JavaScript in client browser refreshes part of the document, essentially going through steps 1-5, but only replacing a portion of what's being displayed (an HTML element).